# Is hidden layer is part of N-layer NN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

When we say 2-layer NN, do we count the hidden layers? If we don't count them it means that the 2-layer NN have 4 layers in total. One hidden layer for first layer and one hidden layer for the second layer, right? I'll be happy for clarification.

Comment: I fear that different people use different terms/meanings. Always a good idea to be more precise, especially in theoretic analysis like for example [Universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem).